# Variable value not correctly increasing

Tags: java, arrays, string

In my code I have a variable, points, that increments based on the consanants and vowels in strings inputted. The method `parseSentence` is supposed to increase points per word but also ignore spaces.

I've tried running a debugger to see where the problem is but the debugger dies when it reaches the for loop in `parseSentence`. The method makes the point variable's value the word's point value instead of adding it to the variable. What could be causing this?

```
import java.util.*;

public class WordGolf1 {

    public static int points = 1;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String Input;
        System.out.println("Enter word: ");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        Input = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Not enough points. " + (100 - points) + " needed.");
        while (points < 100) {
            System.out.println("Enter word: ");
            Input = sc.nextLine();
            parseSentence(Input);
            System.out.println(points + ": points");
            System.out.println("Not enough points. " + (100 - points) + " needed.");
        }
        boolean overshot = true;
        Loop:
        while (overshot = true) {
            if (points == 100) {
                overshot = false;
                break Loop;
            }
            points = 100 - (points - 100);
            System.out.println("Overshot by " + (points - 100) + " points.");
            Input = sc.nextLine();
            parseSentence(Input);
        }
        System.out.println("Congratulations you win!");
        sc.close();
    }

    public static int parseSentence(String input) {
        String[] pieces = input.split("\\s+");
        for (int y = 0; y < pieces.length; y++) {
            if (pieces.length > 1) {
                if (y == 0) {
                    parseWord(input);
                } else {
                    parseWord(input, y);
                }
            } else {
                parseWord(input);
            }
        }
        return points;
    }

    public static int parseWord(String input) {
        String[] pieces = input.split("\\s+");
        String charList = "aeiouyAEIOUY";
        String consanantList
                = "bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxzBCDFGHJKLMNPQRSTVWXZ";
        int pointsTemp = 1;
        for (int x = 0; x < pieces[0].length(); x++) {
            if (charList.indexOf(pieces[0].charAt(x)) != -1) {
                pointsTemp *= 2;
            } else if (consanantList.indexOf(pieces[0].charAt(x))
                    != -1) {
                pointsTemp++;
            }
        }
        points = pointsTemp;
        return points;
    }

    public static int parseWord(String input, int number) {
        String[] pieces = input.split("\\s+");
        String charList = "aeiouyAEIOUY";
        String consanantList
                = "bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxzBCDFGHJKLMNPQRSTVWXZ";
        int pointsTemp = 1;
        for (int x = 0; x < pieces[number].length(); x++) {
            if (charList.indexOf(pieces[number].charAt(x)) != -1) {
                pointsTemp *= 2;
            } else if (consanantList.indexOf(pieces[number].charAt(x)) != -1) {
                pointsTemp++;
            }
        }
        points += pointsTemp;
        return points;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding your question.  I have no issues running and debugging the code.   Are you saying that the integer `points` should be cumulative, and that `pointsTemp` should be simply added to the current `points` value?

Comment: Chris same.. took me a good minute to decipher what he wanted, but it sounds like he is converting words into values every non vowel is +1 and every vowel multiplys the words score by 2. Then he adds these words up and if you are under 100 you are told to enter more words if you are above 100 he reduces your score by 100 although that can fail so I choose % 100 instead. Then if you hit 100 you win the game.

Comment: `while(overshot = true)` should be either `while(overshot == true)` or just `while(overshot)`

Comment: That's what I'm saying @ChrisJ. It should be cumulative but it isn't.

Comment: is that not caused by your `parseSentence` loop stating `points = pointsTemp`?  If you want to add to the class scoped `points`, should you not be stating `points += pointsTemp;`  - of course you're also using `return` redundantly.

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the value returned by the `parseSentence` method.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: I tried to rewrite this to be as close your original code with making the changes I feel where necessary.

Now Obviously your teacher has requirements and we can't go against that, but some points of interest you should keep in mind.

**Multi Splitting**

In your example you split the text to get the amount of words. Then instead of looping the already split text. You are sending the original input and then splitting it again. The "Double" splitting is why you needed "three" methods. If you don't double split you can simply loop the length from the single split and just use a single ParseWord method.

**Deducting Values**

In your example you take away 100 if the player overshot. The problem with this is let's say the person received a score like 200. Then it would loop twice to lower the value submitting the "You overshot message" twice. However let's say by some magical way a score of 100,000,000 was received. Then as you can see we would loop 1 million times to deduct this value essentially creating an not infinite but might as well be infinite loop.

To resolve this problem we simply do the below.

```
Value = Value % 100.
```

This will give us the remainder of our Value between 0 and 99. I.e. **167 will equal 67** and **12384 will be equal 84.**

**Using String (IndexOf)**

What this does is takes the **Character** you provided and loop iterates over the String you provided. The worst case is 12 loops. There's also a lot of other stuff String and IndexOf do that is extra work and I recommend staying away from it if you can.

The alternative solution which I did is take the character and use " | 32" on it. I'm not going to go deep into how bits work, but basically these characters are 8 bit values but we only use 7 of it's bits ranging from 32 to 127. The amount of bits is like the power of 2. so 2^7 = 128 and 2^8 = 256. When we perform the "|" we are turning a bit on so if it's already on it won't change the value.

So in our example let's say we have the value 64.

This is bit 6 turned on. Now we want to turn on bit 5 "32" so the value becomes 96, but if we already had the value 96 and we turn bit 32 on it will still be 32.

**Full List of ASCII Characters..**

https://www.ascii-code.com/

**The Game Loop**

In your example you created "TWO" game loops the first one is when you start off, but once you overshot your score you enter the second loop and forget the first one. The problem is now your "Enter Words" and "You Undershot" code are never used anymore. So all someone will see is the line to enter text with no information on what to do or what occurred unless they overshot then they get the overshot message.

To fix this I made a single Game Loop which processes until the code ends via the SCORE == 100. You can see in the code that we begin every game loop with "Enter Words: " and parse the sentence. Then we add up our score and compare. If we undershot we simply restart the loop and try again. If we overshot we reduce the score and try again. If we succeeded we prompt the user if they would like to play again or end the game. Playing again will set the SCORE to 0 and start over the loop. Ending the game will "BREAK" the loop and cause it to end.

**The Full Working Code With Recommended Changes**

Feel free to comment if you need additional assistance.

```
import java.util.*;

public class WordGolf1 
{

    private static int SCORE = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (true)
        {
            System.out.print("\n\nEnter word: ");

            ParseSentence(sc.nextLine());

            if (SCORE == 100)
            {
                System.out.print("\nYou Won! Would you like to play again: Y/N?");
                if ((sc.nextLine().charAt(0) | 32) == 'y')
                {
                    SCORE = 0;
                    System.out.print("\nResetting Game...");
                } else {
                    break;
                }
            }
            else
            {   
                if (SCORE > 100)
                {
                    int overshot = SCORE - 100;
                    SCORE = SCORE % 100;
                    System.out.print("\nYou Overshot By " + overshot + " Points. You now have " + SCORE + " points.");
                } else {
                    System.out.print("\nYou currently have " + SCORE + " points you need " + (100 - SCORE) + " more.");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static int ParseSentence(String input)
    {
        String[] split = input.split(" ");
        for (Strng s : input)
            SCORE += ParseWord(s);
    }

    private static int ParseWord(String word)
    {
        int value = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); ++i)
        {
            int c = (int)word.charAt(i) | 32;
            if (c == 'a' || c == 'e' || c == 'i' || c == 'o' || c == 'u')
            {
                value *= 2;
            } else {
                value += 1;
            }
        }
        return value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! I know my code is quite redundant but I am doing this project for a class and the class requires 3 methods. My original code had to be rewritten as it made only one method.

Comment: I redid it slightly to be closer to your original example and I provided some feedback with areas you might want to do differently and why and the full code provides these alternative solutions.